# when modeling a component, do you use the top or bottom view?

Tags: pcb-design, datasheet

I'm modeling a component from this [datasheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jwg8k5ush9e9ho/tps22960.pdf?dl=0), they provide both a top view and bottom view of the components seen below, does my pcb footprint represent the top view or the bottom view? This has been very confusing to me.

TOP VIEW:

[image]

BOTTOM VIEW:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top view is standard -- think of it as being able to see through the component X-ray-vision style.  (Your EDA tool will know how to flip the footprint correctly if you tell it to put the part on the back of the board.)

Answer (score 0):

All EDA tools I've used so far use a top view for the footprint.

On the next page, you have an "example board layout" that you can directly use as the footprint.

Comment: the example board layout does not include pin labels, and the layout is symmetric so theres no way to know wether it tells you to use top or bottom :(

Comment: Yes, but the regular "top view" does include the pin labels -- orient it so it matches the footprint, and use these pin labels (and make a dot in the corner, so you know the orientation).